# RF24L01+ VER01 with 10 pins

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

How can I connect this little ship to my Arduino? I can find alot of tutorials how to do it so, but all I find is 8 pins, mine includes 10 pins, and from what I could of understand from searching me myself, that there is 2 pins of VCC and 2 GRN pins.

So I would like to know how to connect this? Not necesserly Arduino, but can someone help me with the pins names at least so I can identify them.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is also not correct for boards with original chip on it. This one is for WaveShare board :

Answer (score 1):

There are some 10pin adapter boards floating around. See e.g. 
[nrf24l01 (8pin) + adapter board (10pin) oops?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22914/nrf24l01-8pin-adapter-board-10pin-oops)

Their pinout looks to be the following.

[image]